# Search for recently deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Moderators and users with 10K+ reputations can search for deleted posts on the advanced search page by specifying `deleted:yes` option. Users with 10K+ also get the following note after search:

> [image: note]

For users who have not enough rep this option doesn't work at all and silently ignored. However user can see a list of **recently deleted own posts** via deleted recent questions/answer links on corresponding sections in the Activity tab of the profile page.

My request is: allow users even with less than 10k to search for own recently deleted posts via advanced search since it can be viewed via profile page.

Comment: "can be viewed via profile page" - not really. Only recent deleted posts, i.e. which has been posted in last 60 days. Otherwise it is "lost" for good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if so, search for deleted posts could return a list of such posts for users with <10K.

Comment: True, but that's covered in the dupe as far as I can see. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard already upvoted dupe question :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the end of chain of duplicates tagged [status-completed], but that question is not about searching for users with <10k. Should the chain of duplicates be broken?

Comment: Dunno about chain, but since you mean only the recently deleted posts, it's different indeed. Edited to focus on that, and reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. From small to large. Accepting this FR can lead to requesting more. I.e. searching not only recently deleted posts but all.

Comment: Well searching for all would not happen, it was declined before as far as I remember.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I meant all for current user only, even if he has <10k.